# Common Lisp apropos and documentation

Tags: common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, sbcl

I am aware of the powerful features offered by the Common Lisp REPL. I am specifically using the SBCL implementation. However, I am not sure my REPL is setup properly and would like to know how to get more power out of the REPL.

For example, I wanted to find the power function to computer 2^3 = 8. This is called `pow` or `power` in many other languages. So I did:

```
CL-USER> (apropos 'pow)
    POW                                                                                                                                                                          
    POWER                                                                                                                                                                        
    :OP-POWER-EXT (bound)                                                                                                                                                        
    :POWERPC (bound)                                                                                                                                                             
    SB-IMPL::*INTEGER-READER-BASE-POWER* (bound)                                                                                                                                 
    SB-IMPL::*POWER-CACHE* (bound)                                                                                                                                               
    SB-IMPL::+POWER-CACHE-INTEGER-LENGTH-LIMIT+ (bound)                                                                                                                          
    SB-IMPL::COMPUTE-POWERS                                                                                                                                                      
    SB-IMPL::POWER                                                                                                                                                               
    SB-IMPL::POWERS-FOR-BASE (fbound)                                                                                                                                            
    SB-INT:POWER-OF-TWO-CEILING (fbound)                                                                                                                                         
    SB-KERNEL:%POW (fbound)                                                                                                                                                      
    SB-KERNEL::POWER                                                                                                                                                             
    SB-KERNEL:SCRUB-POWER-CACHE (fbound)                                                                                                                                         
    ; No value
```

How would I view the documentation of any of these functions? Would I have to "import" any of these "libraries" before I view the documentation? Often I find that the documentation is missing, as the REPL will return `nil.` Where is the documentation? For example I did:

```
CL-USER> (documentation 'power 'function)
```

and it just returned `NIL` but as you can see from the list above given by `apropos`, `power` exists!

Summarizing:

1. How do I find the documentation of functions, data-types, variables etc... (what else is there to look-up documentation for?)?
2. Are `SB-IMPL` and `SB-KERNEL` libraries that are already imported?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Some support in slime: `C-c C-d C-h` to list documentation related functions, e.g. `C-c C-d h` to look up in hyperspec or `C-c C-d d` to `DESCRIBE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> CL-USER> (documentation 'power 'function)
> ```
>
> and it just returned NIL but as you can see from the list above given
>   by apropos, power exists!

The *symbol* `power` exists, but note that it's not `bound` or `fbound` like some of the other symbols are.  Thus is doesn't have a function or value binding.  Lots of symbols exist, even if they don't have a function or value binding.  This can be particularly frustrating in `apropos`, because if you do `(apropos 'name)`, then in reading the form, you've already ensured that there's a symbol `name`.  Sometimes you'll see people use the uninterned symbol notation to avoid this problem.  E.g.:

```
CL-USER> (apropos 'this-already-got-interned)
THIS-ALREADY-GOT-INTERNED
; No value
CL-USER> (apropos '#:but-this-didnt\!)
; No value
```

However, even if `power` did have a function or value binding, there's no guarantee that there'd be documentation available for it. Note that the [documentation for `documentation`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_docume.htm) says:

> Documentation strings are made available for debugging purposes.
>   Conforming programs are permitted to use documentation strings when
>   they are present, but should not depend for their correct behavior on
>   the presence of those documentation strings. An implementation is
>   permitted to discard documentation strings at any time for
>   implementation-defined reasons.

That said, you can still try, and sometimes you'll get useful results:

```
CL-USER> (apropos '#:expt)
EXPT (fbound)
SB-C::EXPT-DERIVE-TYPE-AUX (fbound)
SB-C::EXPT-DERIVE-TYPE-OPTIMIZER (fbound)
...
; No value
CL-USER> (documentation 'expt 'function)
"Return BASE raised to the POWER."
```

In general, if you want to know more about an object, you can use [`describe`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_descri.htm) ([sds pointed this out before I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102323/1281433)).  The output isn't specifically defined, but it may well include the documentation:

```
CL-USER> (describe 'expt)
COMMON-LISP:EXPT
  [symbol]

EXPT names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (BASE POWER)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (NUMBER NUMBER) (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
  Documentation:
    Return BASE raised to the POWER.
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;IRRAT.LISP
; No value
```

In general, these tools can be useful, but if you're looking for a particular function to achieve some task, Google is probably going to be more helpful unless you've already got a good idea of what you're looking for.  After all, the first result in a [Google search for “common lisp hyperspec exponent power”](https://www.google.com/search?q=common%20lisp%20hyperspec%20exponent%20power&oq=common%20lisp%20hyperspec%20exponent%20power&aqs=chrome..69i64.7321j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is a link to the page for `expt`.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to find out more about a lisp object is [`describe`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_descri.htm).

E.g.,

```
* (describe 'expt)

COMMON-LISP:EXPT
  [symbol]

EXPT names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (BASE POWER)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (NUMBER NUMBER) (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
  Derived type: (FUNCTION (T T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Documentation:
    Return BASE raised to the POWER.
  Known attributes: foldable, flushable, unsafely-flushable, movable, recursive, explicit-check
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;IRRAT.LISP
```

To answer your second question: [`import`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_import.htm) manipulates *packages* (namespaces), while [`load`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm) and [`require`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_provid.htm) load libraries from disk. I suggest that you read up the manual and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

`APROPOS` just looks for symbols which contain a string in the current running image. It will also indicate if the symbol has a function, macro and/or value.

If you search for `POWER` amongst the symbols and there is such a symbol, then it does not mean there is such a function.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defun foobar (a) a)
FOOBAR

CL-USER 2 > 'foosym
FOOSYM

CL-USER 3 > (apropos "foo")
FOOBAR (defined)
FOOSYM
```

Thus it makes sense to check out the function `FOOBAR`. There is also a symbol `FOOSYM`, but it has no function definition.

Some Lisp Implementations have enhanced versions or variants of `APROPOS`. LispWorks for example has a GUI-based symbol browser with many search options.

For SBCL your best option is to use it together with GNU Emacs + SLIME.

**To lookup the documentation for a function you have basically two direct options**:

1: call `DOCUMENTATION`:

```
CL-USER 4 > (defun foobar (a) "my foobar is silly" a)
FOOBAR

CL-USER 5 > (documentation 'foobar 'function)
"my foobar is silly"
```

2: use the IDE command to find documentation. Task: read the [SLIME manual](http://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/).

For example in LispWorks I would use the keyboard commands:

- documentation string:  Meta-Control-Shift-a  on the symbol
- LispWorks documentation: Control-Shift-d  on the symbol

Alternative, I could also use the menu or the context-menu to find the documentation.

**To get an overview about built-in math functionality**

Look at the Common Lisp HyperSpec [Numbers Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_number.htm).